# Can I upload an iOS 7 app for testing if I'm using Xcode 4.6?

Tags: ios7, xcode4.6

I have an app made and sent to me. It was developed in Xcode 5 for iOS 7.

I have a Mac running OS X Lion which cannot be upgraded any further, and I’m running Xcode 4.6.3 (the latest version of Xcode for Lion).

I have the completed App files, but I need to make a .API file to upload, so I can test it on my iPhone 4S running iOS 7.

**Is this possible, and if not, what can I do?**

Can Xcode 4.6.3 open the iOS 7 project for me to create an .API file to get it tested on my iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

If a project created in Xcode 5,then it can't be open with xcode 4.6 or previous versions.

Also, as per apple latest review guidelines, "All the apps should build with ios 7 compatibility"

Answer (score -1):

You can run your app from xCode 4.6.3 to your iPhone 4s directly using AdHoc Profile. For IPA, You should update your Mac OSX-Lion to OS X Mavericks(10.9) and install xCode 5.0. Open your application in xCode 5.0 and create the IPA. This is common way for IPA to be working in iOS7 running device!

Comment: "I have a mac which is running OSX-Lion and it cannot be upgraded any further" As OP explains, updating their Mac beyond Lion is a non-option.